# Justification for the definition of relative error, why is it not a metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, approximation, symmetry, floating-point, rounding-error

The *absolute error* and *relative error* operators are very commonly encountered while reading about topics from the fields of floating-point arithmetics or approximation theory.

Absolute error is
${ae(a, b)} = {\left\lvert{a - b}\right\rvert}$, where the first argument, $a$, is an approximation of the second argument, $b$.

Relative error is ${re(a, b)} = {\left\lvert{1 - \frac{a}{b}}\right\rvert}$, where the first argument, $a$, is an approximation of the second argument, $b$.

Interestingly, relative error loses the symmetry apparent in the definition of absolute error. I can tell that this has something to do with putting more *weight* on the accurate value than on its approximation, however I wonder about a clearer explanation.

Mark S. noted below that the definition of relative error follows if we take "relative error" to be short for "absolute error relative to the magnitude of $b$". But this still doesn't show why would this particular description or definition be desirable compared to other possible definitions.

One thing I've noticed is that this simple function behaves very similarly to relative error, but **is** symmetric: ${f(a, b)} = {\left\lvert{ln{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}}\right\rvert} = {ae{\left(ln{\left(a\right)}, ln{\left(b\right)}\right)}}$. How appropriate is it as an alternative definition of relative error?

The symmetric function $f$ is, sadly, not defined when $a$ and $b$ are of opposite sign. For example, for $a = 0.1$ and $b = -0.1$, the relative error takes the value of *two*, but $f$ is undefined. I'm not sure if $f$ can be appropriately extended, but, in any case, this doesn't seem too important, as such huge values of relative error can usually be special-cased.

EDIT: this plot of floating-point round-to-nearest rounding "error" from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $9$, for a floating-point format with a three-bit significand, might be interesting:

[image: precision 3]

Relative error is red, while the symmetric function $f$ is blue. So it seems that $f$ results in slightly higher maximal rounding "errors", but the two functions nonetheless behave very alike. This discrepancy seems to vanish as the significand grows in length, though; this is a similar plot for 16-bit floating-point precision (the two functions line up perfectly):

[image: precision 16]

Comment: Forgive me if I'm way off the mark, but are you already comfortable with the everyday English language meaning of "X, relative to Y"? Either way, I never thought of the definition of "relative error" needing more justification than that, so I'm curious if you could expand on what it is you would like justified.

Comment: Well I'm focused on the property of the symmetry of the two variables. It (curiously?) doesn't hold for relative error. And I wonder how acceptable is my alternative definition of relative error.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase: since any symmetric definition wouldn't satisfy the English meaning of "relative", I find any symmetric candidate for "relative error" (yours or otherwise) not personally acceptable.

Comment: What **useful** thing does your log definition accomplish? The relationship between the actual value and the approximation is anything but symmetric. The actual value is the important one, while the approximation is the one that is known. The purpose of error calculation is to put a useful bound on how far the actual value is from the approximation. I don't see how your version makes this easier (it seems to make it harder) or set tighter bounds (it seems to give slightly looser bounds). So I don't see any advantage.

Comment: Giving an example: A 1 cm error on a 12 cm reading and a 1 cm error on a 264 cm reading have different significances. Although the absolute error is same (1 cm) in both cases, the relative error in first case 1/12 is bigger than in the second case. (Suggesting the first error is more significant)